# What is different between DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) and DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dateadd

What is different between

```
DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())
```

and

```
DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Could someone help to show example case, how to use them?

Comment: If you do a select with both values, you would quickly see it

Comment: @PatrickHonorez Hi, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first version includes the time component of `GETDATE()`.  The second does not.  So, if the current time is 2018-01-01T05:43:26, then the first version returns:

```
2018-01-02T05:43:26
```

The second removes the time component, so it returns:

```
2018-01-02T00:00:00
```

I think a better version to get midnight when the next day starts is:

```
dateadd(day, 1, cast(getdate() as date))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first Version `DateAdd()` Adding Date in Current Date.

In your Second Version first Execute `DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())` It Gives you Date Different and After that It Will Add One Day in `DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())` Result.

Comment: @akkapolk WelCome.